# Alternate images based on users color preference without using JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I have a simple static site built with `HTML` and `CSS`. Here's a snippet of the HTML code:

```html
<body>
    <h1>My static site</h1>
    <p>This is a simplified example of my static site.</p>
    <p>I don't use PHP, JavaScript, or any other programming language</p>
    <img style="width: 40%;" src="image.png" />
</body>
```

In the CSS, I've set specific rules using `prefers-color-scheme: dark` for users who have configured their devices for dark mode:

```css
body {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: monospace;
    max-width: 130ex;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

I usually aim to use images with transparencies to ensure they look good in both light and dark modes. However, for some images, this approach isn't sufficient, and they become difficult to discern in certain situations. In such cases, I resort to duplicating the image and using separate images for light and dark modes:

```html
<img style="width: 40%;" src="image.png" />
<img style="width: 40%;" src="dark-image.png" />
```

[image: light image]
[image: dark image]

Is there a method to specify which image to use without resorting to programming languages or cookies (perhaps through `CSS`)? Alternatively, is there a `CSS`-based approach to darken an image for dark mode without duplicating it?

Or is it necessary to implement a `JavaScript` solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can add a class to the images and then target them with media queries:

```css
.only-on-dark {
  display: none;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .only-on-dark {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .only-on-light {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="only-on-dark" src="//via.placeholder.com/200/000000/ffffff" />
<img class="only-on-light" src="//via.placeholder.com/200/ffffff/000000" />
```

Answer (score 8):

A more semantic way to solve this issue is using the `<picture>` tag with some inline media queries.

The first two `<source>` tags change the image based on the given `media` rules, which in this case are the color preferences. The bottom `img` tag is the default image that works outside the given `media` rules.

This system is also great because it can be used with other media rules to change the images. For example, you can change the media to respond to a specific screen width.

```html
<picture>
  <!-- User prefers light mode: -->
  <source srcset="light.png" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)"/>

  <!-- User prefers dark mode: -->
  <source srcset="dark.png"  media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"/>

  <!-- User has no color preference: -->
  <img src="light.png"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: I think this is preferable solution, since it also **prevents downloading** the hidden variant.

Answer (score 3):

Although the excellent answers above perfectly answer the problem (and solve it), I would like to add, for whom it may be useful, another possible solution that I have found investigating the problem, just as an addition.

The solution is given taking into account that what I do is to make a copy of the image by inverting the colors (this cannot be done in all, in many inverting the color is desirable). In such a way that I get two images, one dark and one light.

But, why invest it in another image and not invest it in CSS in case we find ourselves in dark mode?

We can do this with:

```html
<img class="color-invertible" src="image.png"/>
```

And adding to `prefers-color-scheme: dark`:

```css
.color-invertible {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

In this way we would only have one image, and we will indicate through its class the images that can be inverted in dark mode and those that cannot.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `img` you could add a class to it and toggle the display depending on the `prefer-color-scheme`.

If you use a `background-color`, you could set a different background inside the media.

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .light {
    display: none;
  }
  .bg-container {
    background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/200/200");
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .dark {
    display: none;
  }
  .bg-container {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x200");
  }
}

.bg-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" class="dark">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="" class="light">

<div class="bg-container"></div>
```